# how can validate only some fields in Vee-validate 3.x?

Tags: validation, vee-validate

version: Vee-validate 3.x

sometime i want to validate only some fields, sometime i want to validate all fields. how can i do it use ValidationObserver ?

```
<template>
  <ValidationObserver  ref="validationObserver">
    <form>
      <ValidationProvider name="E-mail" rules="required|email" v-slot="{ errors }">
        <input v-model="email" type="email">
        <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
      </ValidationProvider>

      <ValidationProvider name="First Name" rules="required|alpha" v-slot="{ errors }">
        <input v-model="firstName" type="text">
        <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
      </ValidationProvider>

      <ValidationProvider name="Last Name" rules="required|alpha" v-slot="{ errors }">
        <input v-model="lastName" type="text">
        <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
      </ValidationProvider>


    </form>
  </ValidationObserver>

 <button @click="validateSome">validateSome</button>
 <button @click="validateAll">validateAll</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods:{
         validateAll(){
               this.$refs.validationObserver.validate().then(isOk=>console.log(isOk))
         }
         validateSome(){
              // if i want to validate only [email,firstName] fields, how can i do ?
         }
    }
}
</script>
```

how can i  finish  validateSome methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually nest Validation Observers!  So, try wrapping the two fields you want to validate separately sometimes in another ValidationObserver, give it a ref and call it the same way you call the outside one in `validateAll`.

```
<ValidationObserver ref="validationObserver">
<form>
  <ValidationObserver ref="innerObs">
  <ValidationProvider name="E-mail" rules="required|email" v-slot="{ errors }">
    <input v-model="email" type="email">
    <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
  </ValidationProvider>

  <ValidationProvider name="First Name" rules="required|alpha" v-slot="{ errors }">
    <input v-model="firstName" type="text">
    <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
  </ValidationProvider>
  </ValidationObserver>

  <ValidationProvider name="Last Name" rules="required|alpha" v-slot="{ errors }">
    <input v-model="lastName" type="text">
    <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
  </ValidationProvider>

</form>
</ValidationObserver>
```

Then your function like this:

```
     validateSome(){
        this.$refs.innerObs.validate().then(isOk=>console.log(isOk))
     }
```